# Bootstrap calendar date not able to select in Windows 10 edge browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap calendar date not able to select in Windows 10 edge browser.  Does any one have a solution? using plugin http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(
        nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(),
        nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0
    );

    var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
        onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()); //newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            checkout.setValue(newDate);
        }
        checkin.hide();
        $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');

    var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
        onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() < checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : ''; //<=
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        checkout.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
});
```

Comment: Your link is not working ?